# PostgreSQL tweaks for faster huge DB cleanup

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I have a Python-Django script that takes our production database (150GB) and removes a ton of stuff from it, basically leaving only last 2 weeks of data for development purposes and produces just 6GB database at the end. Currently this script takes about 36 hours to finish with the given computational cloud resources (rather small and cheap ones). I think that there should be some postgresql-based tweaks like disabling auto-vacuum or disabling the indexes rebuilding to speed this up. Are there any?

Comment: Is the production DB left unchanged and you essentially want limited export? Or are you actually deleting the data from the production DB?

Comment: Please tell us you haven't disabled auto vacuum ?.

Comment: @VynlJunkie I did not yet:)

Comment: @IainShelvington it's a fresh copy of production database and I essentially want limited export